# Android scrolling issue webview inside scrollview with viewpager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, scrollview, orientation

I have a `viewpager` which contains a layout with `scrollview` as parent and `webview` as child.I had never faced a problem with portrait mode however in landscape mode it's acting very strange.

The screen is taking portrait height(which i'm assuming) in landscape too.
So the `scrollview` is getting activated when scrolling down.

If I block the touch by putting `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` but if I do that i'm unable to move to next page.

I gave the following in configChanges

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Here's my main xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ScrollView
android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/topMostLayout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </RelativeLayout>



<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <com.mango.expert.utils.FullCard_ShadowLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_shadow_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:sl_cornerRadius="7dp"
        app:sl_shadowColor="@color/shadow">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/dummyLayoutForViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dummyLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/for_full_card_bg" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.mango.expert.utls.FullCard_ShadowLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Some tags are missing, i'm finding difficulty in pasting xml here.xml is totally fine.
Any help would be really great.Forgot to mention that webview is in Fragment and Scrollview is in main layout

Comment: theres no need to add webview inside scrollview

Comment: If i remove scrollview i'm unable to see the full content in landscape mode

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement **ScrollView** for **WebView**. It's already have that feature it self.

Comment: I tried it by removing scrollview, but i'm unable to see the full content in landscape mode as its taking portrait height for landscape

Comment: I think you have not applied height as "match_parnet" in your xml file.

Comment: ,I've given match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Enable NestedScrolling on parent layout:

```
parent.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

or wrap your entire layout inside NestedScrollView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout ...>
           <ViewPager ... />
        </FrameLayout >
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll try it and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately didn't worked, it blocked normal webview scrolling also in portrait mode